# Swift, UIView to location in 2D array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiview

I am currently working on a project where i have a grid as in the image here. 
[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46r6h.png).
I had planned on making the grid be of 10 x 10 UIImagesviews, or UIView's. So that each square can contain an image.

I also have a 2Darray containing 0's likes so:

```
[
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
].
```

My question is, how can i make my view return a row and column for the grid. when a user selects a square? so that i can change the 0 to a 1, at that location.

My inital thought is use touchesbegan, and return the x.y. coordinates of the screen and attempt to match them with rows and columns. But i was hoping for a more reliable way of doing this, or just to hear of other options?.

Thanks - Nikolai

Comment: Firstly view has a tag property. view.tag

Comment: How about using grid of `UIButton`s? A bit more heavyweight solution, but probably the most straightforward

Comment: If it's just a simple tap, `UIButton` would be better than `UIImageView`. But I'd recommend a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Secondly, you can use UITableView's (UICollectionView's) didSelect method and get it's IndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like nothing else but `UICollectionView`. Your "2DArray" is the dataSource of the collection view and in your `UICollectionViewDelegate` you can detect

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
             didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview

For this purpose you need to play a little with the collection view's layout so that you have 10 cells per row, and 10x10 cells in the section. If it suits your needs you can rather have 10 sections with 10 cells each. (The first case seems better from what you have described)

Comment: ofcourse, hadn't even thought of using a collection view, i will try this out. Thanks :-D